# How to implement a dynamic image to my report?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, reportviewer

### People, please help, I'm about to loose my mind. How to properly implement the external dynamic image to a rdlc. What is wrong with my code?

```
Dim param As List(Of ReportParameter) = New List(Of ReportParameter)
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImage...s = True

param.Add(New ReportParameter("paramImage", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "") + "http://localhost/ToursV2(ToursOnly)/logos/dominion.jpg"))

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param)
```

---

The report runs but without my dynamic images.

Answer (score 0):

This is a curious bit.

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "") + 
     "http://localhost/ToursV2(ToursOnly)/logos/dominion.jpg"))
```

Assuming the Request Url is something like `"http://localhost/SomeFile.aspx"` then this should emit something along the lines of:

```
http://localhosthttp://localhost/ToursV2(ToursOnly)/logos/dominion.jpg
```

Which is probably not what you had in mind.  You might want to run an inspector on that line of code.